# remapping numeric items in data frame to labels with nested dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, nested

build data :

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'ebe5eb3c': [1, 3, 4, -1, 1], 
        'd9cd9ja6': [1, 1, 0, 1, 0], 
        '32aq-c79': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2], 
        'e2c-8b7e': [1, 4, 2, 2, 1]})

mydict = dict()
mydict = ([['ebe5eb3c',[{'value': '1', 'response': 'None'}, {'value': '2', 'response': 'Several days'}, {'value': '4', 'response': 'Nearly every day'},{'value': '-7', 'response': 'Every day'},{'value': '-1', 'response': 'Do not know'}]],
          ['d9cd9ja6',[{'value': '1', 'response': 'Yes'}, {'value': '0', 'response': 'No', 'please go to question': '7'}]],
          ['z2aq-c79',[{'value': '1', 'response': 'True'},{'value': '2', 'response': 'False'}]],
          ['e2c-8b7e',[{'value': '1', 'response': '5-10 years'}, {'value': '2', 'response': '10-15 years'},{'value': '3', 'response': '15-20 years'},{'value': '4', 'response': '20-25 years'}]]])
```

I have a dataframe that has multiple columns, and rows correspond to answers per subject. I need to remap the original numeric value within the dataframe to the actual labels that are presented in the dictionary (mydict). The dictionary is neste with the question identifer mathcing the column name as the key, and the value level includes multiple different items.

This is just an example dataset - the reason i need to do *something like this* is that there are hundreds of these columns..

I have tried looping through columns and applying .map and .replace but no luck.

Any suggesions are very welcome. Thank you!

Comment: In your example the `mydict` is of type `list`. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Andrej - good point. actually no i create a dictionary from a template database with something like the following `mydict2 = columns=dict(zip(df['question'], col2["response"]))` - but i didnt include the exact dictionary here for privacy reasons. can a list be used here as a proxy? if you `dict(mydict)` that should sort it?

Comment: Ooh.. can we skip that step of creating mydict2 and just map the two dataframes?  Can you post the original df and also your expected output df?

Comment: Hi @ScottBoston - i won't post the original data frame as it is massive. and the question-answer information in the mydict comes from a very very deeply nested json which stores it answer info as a nested dict  - so in my data frame all that info per question is stored as a list within a cell (i know its a bit messy..but this is the data i am given and makes sense for the rest of the data there..) so mapping data frames doesn't work. what i would like to do is for instance replace for question ebe5eb3c answer 1 with the label 'none'. does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments:

I'm assuming, you have dictionary in this form:

```py
mydict = {
    "ebe5eb3c": [
        {"value": "1", "response": "None"},
        {"value": "2", "response": "Several days"},
        {"value": "4", "response": "Nearly every day"},
        {"value": "-7", "response": "Every day"},
        {"value": "-1", "response": "Do not know"},
    ],
    "d9cd9ja6": [
        {"value": "1", "response": "Yes"},
        {"value": "0", "response": "No", "please go to question": "7"},
    ],
    "z2aq-c79": [
        {"value": "1", "response": "True"},
        {"value": "2", "response": "False"},
    ],
    "e2c-8b7e": [
        {"value": "1", "response": "5-10 years"},
        {"value": "2", "response": "10-15 years"},
        {"value": "3", "response": "15-20 years"},
        {"value": "4", "response": "20-25 years"},
    ],
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for k, v in mydict.items():
    if k in data.columns:
        data[k] = data[k].apply(
            lambda x: next(
                (d["response"] for d in v if d["value"] == str(x)), x
            )
        )
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
           ebe5eb3c d9cd9ja6  32aq-c79     e2c-8b7e
0              None      Yes         1   5-10 years
1                 3      Yes         2  20-25 years
2  Nearly every day       No         1  10-15 years
3       Do not know      Yes         1  10-15 years
4              None       No         2   5-10 years
```

Comment: That awesome thank you so much!  A secondary question as well if you have the time is - how would you go about doing the same for cells that include multiple answers?